# How to find 1st occurrence of "VB" but ignore "VBN"?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this string: `aa VBN bbb VB cccc`.
I want to return the index of "VB", but not "VBN".

Was thinking about String.find("VB "), so as to skip "VBN", but didn't work.

What would be the quickest way to do it?

Comment: How are you currently doing it, and what's the specific performance issue?

Comment: Cannot think of a good way other than use regular expression. But want to avoid it. So no good way for me yet.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid regex? What are your constraints? What do you mean *"didn't work"*, given you've accepted an answer using the same method?

Comment: sorry i looked at the test result wrong initially for "VB ", the output was kind of messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'aa VBN bbb VB cccc'
print (string.find ('VB '))
```